# SQL Server 2012 bare minimum config for normal usage?

Tags: sql-server, sql

I would like to install SQL Server 2012 with the bare minimum required. I just want a local database and to be able to create/edit/query tables/write queries in the GUI editor.

Which of the configuration tick boxes would satisfy this? There are a lot of options which I have no idea what they do. I want a small installation.

Please see:
[image]

Comment: Why not simply install the express edition.

Answer (score 3):

All you need to install is **SQL Server Database Engine**. For the bare minimum, you won’t need any of the Database Engine sub-features: SQL Server Replication, Full-text and Semantic Extractions for Search, and Data Quality Services

The features available in the SQL Server Enterprise installation are:

- **SQL Server Database Engine** – enables "storing, processing, and securing data, replication, full-text search, tools for managing relational and XML data, and the Data Quality Services (DQS) server". This will enable you to work on a database and create/edit/query tables and other database objects in SQL Server Management Studio Query Editor, what you asked for
- **SQL Server  Analysis Services (SSAS)** - enables OnLine Analytical Processing (OLAP) and data mining
  •   SQL Server Reporting Services (SSRS) – enables creating, managing, and deploying interactive, tabular, graphical, or free-form reports  that include data visualization, charts, and maps
- **SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS)**– enables building complex solutions for enterprise-level data integration and data transformation
- **Master Data Services**
- **Data Quality Services**
- **Management tools** – there are several components - SQL Server Management Studio, SQL Server Configuration Manager, SQL Server Profiler, Database Engine Tuning Advisor, Data Quality Client, SQL Server Data Tools, and Connectivity Components. The only one that is a must in your scenario is **SQL Server Management Studio** (SSMS)

As you’re a SQL Server newbie, I highly recommend the [MS SQL Server sample database](http://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com/releases/view/93587) AdventureWorks

Useful resources:

[Installation for SQL Server 2012](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb500469.aspx)

[Install SQL Server 2012](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb500395.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

"Small" and "SQL Server" really don't go very well together without a negation in there somewhere, but installing *Database Engine Services* (without any of the subcomponents) as well as SQL Server Management Studio should get you a fairly minimalistic installation that will allow you to do the basic stuff but little else.

I'm not sure if you can/need to select SSMS separately or if it is considered a part of the DES, and don't exactly fancy downloading the whole thing just to check.